# Database is not updating ! No error in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Database is not getting updated after submitting. I am not even getting an error.
Here I'm trying to retrieve the values from a database and displaying in the HTML Table format and also user can update the values from here. So when I change the value here and submit the database is not getting updated.

```
  <?php

    print"<center><h3><a href=\"index.html\">Go Back</a></h3><br>"; 


    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','tpsadmin','tps')or die("Cannot connect to DB");
    mysql_select_db('traffic',$con)or die("Cannot select DB");


    $query = "SELECT * FROM emergency";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

    // Count table rows
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    //UPDATE  `emergency` SET  `t_sigid` =  '2',`e_priority` =  '3' WHERE  `emergency`.`e_jid` =70;

    if( isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $sql1 = "UPDATE emergency SET 
                e_latitude='{$_POST['e_latitude'][$i]}', 
                e_longitude='{$_POST['e_longitude'][$i]}', 
                t_sigid='{$_POST['t_sigid'][$i]}', 
                e_priority='{$_POST['e_priority'][$i]}'   
                WHERE e_jid='$id[$i]'"; 
            $result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }


    if($result1){
        header("location: em_disp.php");
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>



    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function mm_jumpmenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
      eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
      if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <title>Emergency Table - Update</title>
    </head>

    <body>


    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table border="5" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#808080" width="50&#37;" text-align="center" id="AutoNumber2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
    <tr>
    <td align="center">e_jid</td> 
    <td align="center">amb_id</td> 
    <td align="center">e_latitude</td> 
    <td align="center">e_longitude</td> 
    <td align="center">t_sigid</td> 
    <td align="center">e_priority</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td align="left"><?php $id[]=$rows['e_jid']; ?><?php echo $rows['e_jid']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['amb_id']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="e_latitude[]" type="text" id="e_latitude" value="<?php echo $rows['e_latitude']; ?>" size="10"></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="e_longitude[]" type="text" id="e_longitude" value="<?php echo $rows['e_longitude']; ?>" size="10"></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="t_sigid[]" type="text" id="t_sigid" value="<?php echo $rows['t_sigid']; ?>" size="10"></td>
    <td align="center"><input name="e_priority[]" type="text" id="e_priority" value="<?php echo $rows['e_priority']; ?>" size="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Please some one help me. thanks !

Comment: `e_jid='$id[$i]'` should not have `'` as it is an integer.

Comment: replace `$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error())` with `echo "$sql1"`, and post the queries that get printed.

Comment: Does `if( isset($_POST['Submit'])){` verify TRUE after post ?

Comment: imho `for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){` looks wrong. Either your `WHERE`-clause is enough to qualify the "to be updated" entries, or its not. I dont see why you need to eval $count and or the prior `SELECT *` on `emergency` table.

Comment: @Ejay here is the query output.
"UPDATE emergency SET e_latitude='13.786584000000', e_longitude='77.996540000000', t_sigid='2', e_priority='3' WHERE e_jid=UPDATE emergency SET e_latitude='0.000000000000', e_longitude='0.000000000000', t_sigid='3', e_priority='2' WHERE e_jid=''"

Comment: There is no _id_ after `WHERE e_jid=` in printed query which means that `$id[$i]` doesn't hold a value or isnt' a variable at all. so you probably want to replace `WHERE e_jid='$id[$i]'"` with `WHERE e_jid=$id"` assuming you've a single `$id` for which you want to update all records in database table.

Comment: @Ejay I want multiple rows to be updated !
http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/517a57124780e3-10391876

I think you'll get my point by looking the image.

Comment: that depends on how you construct the variable `$id`. Doing a `var_dump($id)` before the `for` loop will clarify the situation

Comment: Love SQL injection attack holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Have you seen my answer ??

Comment: @PradeepG : Can you please give any response to my 2 reply

Answer (score 2):

You forget the curly braces at `$id[$i]`.

That, and don't put `$_POST` values directly in your query. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

There is more wrong with your code by the way:

1. the `header` might not work on other places, as you output data at line 1 (you seem to rely on some server setting)
2. This: `<?php $id[]=$rows['e_jid']; ?>` does nothing else than generating a PHP notice.

Comment: `header()` might work if `output_buffering` is enabled (which is by default on a lot of places)

Answer (score 0):

It seems `t_sigid`,`e_priority` and `e_jid` are integer. so  below code is safer.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $t_sigid=intval($_POST['t_sigid'][$i]);
    $e_priority=intval($_POST['e_priority'][$i]);
    $e_jid=intval($id[$i]);
    $sql1 = "UPDATE emergency SET 
        e_latitude='{$_POST['e_latitude'][$i]}', 
        e_longitude='{$_POST['e_longitude'][$i]}', 
        t_sigid='$t_sigid', 
        e_priority='$e_priority'   
        WHERE e_jid='$e_jid'"; 
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

EDIT 1:

change

```
  <td align="left"><?php $id[]=$rows['e_jid']; ?><?php echo $rows['e_jid']; ?></td>
```

to

```
   <td align="left"><input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['e_jid']; ?>" size="10"></td>
```

and also change `$e_jid=intval($id[$i]);` which i mentioned above to `$e_jid=intval($_POST['id'][$i]);`

Answer (score 0):

**You never POST `$id[]` !**

I used to POST it :

`<input type="hidden" name="idArray[]" value="<?php echo $rows['e_jid']; ?>" >`

and toget it

`WHERE e_jid={$_POST['idArray'][$i]}";`

You should note the following points.

- Never make real updates in the development stage.
- Watch with "View page source code" always at the html generated.
- To keep it simple, always use just a few data from tables.
- SQL: String data in quotes. Numbers without quotes.

You can use following code to test

```
...
Here, come in, your instructions database.
should be : mysqli or PDO instructions.
...

if( isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $sql1 = "UPDATE emergency SET 
                e_latitude='{$_POST['e_latitude'][$i]}' 
                WHERE e_jid={$_POST['idArray'][$i]}"; 
                echo "sql ".$sql1."<br />\n";
        }
    if($result1){
       ... Database close action...
       header("location: em_disp.php");
       }
    }

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table border="5" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#808080" width="50&#37;" text-align="center" id="AutoNumber2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
      <tr>
         <td align="center">e_jid</td> 
         <td align="center">amb_id</td> 
         <td align="center">e_latitude</td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    while($rows=....){
    ?>
  <tr>
         <td align="left"><?php echo $rows['e_jid']; ?></td>
          <input type="hidden" name="idArray[]" value="<?php echo $rows['e_jid']; ?>" >
         <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['amb_id']; ?></td>                              
         <td align="center"><input name="e_latitude[]" type="text" id="e_latitude" value="<?php echo $rows['e_latitude']; ?>" size="10"></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  <tr>
         <td colspan="6" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Watch with "View page source code" always at the html generated.
Looks good :

[image]

The output after submit :

[image]

**Other actions only when it is working properly until then.**

If you had followed this, never had your question looked like this.

`Database is not updating ! No error in PHP & MySQL` !